# Two Objects Became Linked in Blender - How to Select / Deselect Just One?

Tags: selections, blender

For some reason I can't seem to select just one object in Blender. In this case I only want to select the square on the right.

[image]

But when I select it, both squares become highlighted. I think the reason for this is because the square on the left was selected when I added the other one. So now they are 'conjoined'. I've already tried to command + z a hundred times but I've gone back as far as I can. Any other way to delete only one of these cubes in Blender?

Comment: there's a specific site for Blender questions: [blender.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate them by loose parts.

1. With the object selected, go to edit mode (Tab)
2. Press P and select by "By Loose Parts"

If you want to delete one of the cubes, go into edit mode and select all of the vertices of the box you want to delete, and manually delete the object.